# How to fix td height as table height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Code:

```
<table width="80%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="5%" style="height:120%;">
      <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum" />
      <apex:pageblockTable value="{!ob}" var="o" style="width:100%;height:100%;" align="center">
        <apex:column HeaderValue="S.NO" style="font-size:20px;font-style:Montepetrum;color:#808080">
          <apex:outputText value="{!FLOOR(rowNum)}" />
          <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}" />
        </apex:column>
      </apex:pageblockTable>
    </td>
    <td width="95%">
      <apex:pageblockTable value="{!ob}" var="o" style="width:100%;" align="center" id="myTable">
        <apex:column>
          <apex:inputField value="{!o.Order_numbering__c}" id="getindex" style="width:30px;display:none;" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column HeaderValue="Nicomatic P/N" value="{!o.Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!o.Or_clientpn__c}" HeaderValue="Client P/N" />
        <apex:column value="{!o.Quantity_Ordered__c}" HeaderValue="Qunatity" />
        <apex:column value="{!o.Requested_Date__c}" HeaderValue="Requested Date" />
        <apex:column value="{!o.Discount__c}" HeaderValue="Discount" />
        <apex:column value="{!o.Unit_price__c}" HeaderValue="Unit price" />
        <apex:column HeaderValue="Row Up">
          <apex:commandButton onClick="MoveUp.call(this);insert_numbers()" rerender="mytable" action="{!save}" value="Up">&#8679;</apex:commandbutton>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column HeaderValue="Row Down">
          <apex:commandButton onClick="MoveDown.call(this);insert_numbers()" rerender="mytable" action="{!save}" value="Down">&#8681;</apex:commandbutton>
        </apex:column>
      </apex:pageblocktable>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to set `td`'s `height` same as `table`'s, how can I do it? I am using two `td`s as different data, first `td` does not exactly fit in the table. How can I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: use `line-height:45px` for `td`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing height of main **`td`** will not work at all. You will need to increase height of each **`td`** in your first table.

Try giving class where you have given `height:120%`

```
<td width="5%" class="fixTdHeight">
```

Then write in CSS:

```
.fixTdHeight td {line-height:45px; /*change as per your needs*/}
```

Comment: it is not fixed .it has to change according to table height

Comment: How to connect this td height equal to table height